# https request with rest assured in java

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a .pdf file on s3 and i want to check the status of this .pdf via hitting s3 url like https://s3.xyz?hello/abc.pdf
I have written code like:-
Assert.assertEquals(given().request("CONNECT",jp.getString("rurl")).statusCode(),200, " Status of rurl is not 200:- " +jp.getString("rurl"))

where rurl like https://s3.xyz?hello/abc.pdf
this code prints status as 403 but when i checked this api it returns 200 and because of this assertion my test case fails every time.
please revert, m i doing something wrong.
How to check apis with https protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) issue. Depending on the framework/server you are using this can be fixed by adding necessary HTTP headers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS